# NASA at sIxty years, will there be a new moonshot mandate?

Tags: nasa, apollo-program, crewed-spaceflight, policy

NASA is sixty years old still going strong.

There are few organizations that have made such an impact to man's quest for knowledge in such a short time span. The contributions are many, and its contributions are in diverse fields such as, physics, medicine, math, as well as the exploration of space.

Now, does the agency seek to explore the moon with manned missions once again, a new, proverbial moonshot?

Comment: I've adjusted the grammar a bit to make your question clearer. It is a *very* good question, and it may have been answered previously in this site, or it may receive a new answer. Either way, an answer will mention that while NASA may propose or explore the feasibility of various missions, it is the branch of the government in charge of funding NASA who decides (and then re-decides, and then re-decides, and then re-decides) what NASA will do.

Comment: I think this question can only be answered by delving deep into US polics, which is both speculative, and probably off-topic here.

Comment: I think it can be seen as a straigjhtforward question about current the  NASA mission as set by the US government. As such it might be quite easy to google and possibly answered before, but I don't think it's off topic or opinion-based.

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi politics, like it or not, is a fundamental aspect of space exploration, and so a question who's answer may need to address in part the political process of funding space exploration is no less on-topic because of that. The OP may not be familliar with the situation, and so a *an answer to the question* would be the right thing here, not an insta-close for off-topic. My goodness, the politics of spaceflight is certainly on-topic!

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi Just search this site for [President Bush](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=president+bush), or [president carter](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=president+carter), or [Nixon](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=nixon), or [Obama](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=obama), or [Trump](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=trump), or [Pence](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=pence)

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi Or see the questions [Where can I find “Space policy directive 1”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23987/12102), or [What ULA innovations was Michael Gass alluding to during latest U.S. Senate address?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3917/12102), or [What is/will be the function of the United States National Space Council?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22154/12102), or [International Collaboration on Large-Scale Manned Space Exploration Projects](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/5384/12102), or...

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi ...[What role does the NASA deputy administrator play?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9028/12102), or [Does Star Trek's adherence to naval tradition have roots in NASA or earlier real organizations?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8095/12102), or [What is the Trump-era path to deep space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22927/12102) for answers which needed to include some discussion of politics. There may be an answer already to this question, in which case marking it as duplicate would be the right way to proceed. That's blocked by faux off-topic insta-closers.

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi oh, and don't forget to search for [Putin](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=putin) as well!

Comment: I diagree with the close votes. The question has a fairly simple answer not based on opinion.

Comment: @uhoh I wouldn't say that discussing politics is off topic per se, but speculating about future developments of politics seems off topic to me. For the record, I didn't downvote. I just think that the question needs to be specified in a way that allowes a specific, non-speculative answer.

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi that's different than saying "... this question can only be answered by delving deep into US politics..." and answers that include some degree of speculation are well received here all the time.

Answer (score 6):

Yes and no. Every new president sets a mandate for NASA. The past few administrations have been setting mandates for Mars missions, the current administration wants to go to the Moon.

The big difference between all these and the Apollo project is NASA's budget. The Apollo mandate included a huge increase in NASA's budget, to 4% of the total federal budget. These days, [NASA's budget is only 0.5%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budget_of_NASA) of the total federal budget and new mandates are not accompanied by a budget increase. So any large-scale mandate such as Mars or Moon missions ends up being unattainable before the next election (and the next potential change in mandate).

The most recent mandate [is by president Trump](https://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2017/12/11/569936446/president-trump-is-sending-nasa-back-to-the-moon):

> President Trump has formally told NASA to send U.S. astronauts back to the moon. "The directive I'm signing today will refocus America's space program on human exploration and discovery," he said.

NASA has huge ongoing commitments (programs like the ISS) that it can't cancel at a whim to free up money for a Moon or Mars mission.

NASA has done lots of work that will inform a Mars mission if it ever gets off the ground. For example, the ISS has been very valuable in teaching us how we can live in space for longer periods, which is research we'll need for e.g. a Mars mission.

Comment: Also Apollo program took MOST part of NASA budget that time, but now SLS/Orion do not take most part of current NASA budget.

Comment: I wonder if this could use an update?

Answer (score 2):

A second manned Moon mission would be nothing new. What about a combination of a unmanned moon rover(s) with a lander for samples return?

The rover(s) could gather samples durings months in a large area and bring them to the landers return module. This could be done with a much smaller rocket than a Saturn V. Several rockets may be used for transport of the rovers and the sample return module.

Comment: Not a second manned (or crewed) moon mission, but a second _project_.  The first project had six, seven or nine crewed moon missions depending on how you count.